# Differentiate WebSockets from two web browser instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

I have a Node js application. It requires 3 websocket servers on 3 different ports. On the front end, 3 websockets connect to each port

```
[Browser.WebSocketClient:500] <--> [NodeJs.WebSocketServer:500]
[Browser.WebSocketClient:501] <--> [NodeJs.WebSocketServer:501]
[Browser.WebSocketClient:502] <--> [NodeJs.WebSocketServer:502]
```

On the front end, when the application loads, each socket is created and connects independently. At some point on the server side, I need to co-ordinate all three connected clients so that a manager is aware that they are all from the same browser instance. This would be easy enough using IP address, but its possible to open a second web browser and have 3 more sockets connect, and on and on (and I need this for testing). Timestamp is not reliable enough to work (suppose both browser tabs were opened at the same time).

I know one solution could be to send a uuid through the websocket on connection, but that would be from the front end, which means it could easily be spoofed (Javascript ftw).

Is there any way to identify these three sockets as coming from the same browser instance? It would essentially have to be something built in that I could use as a uuid.

Comment: I liked your uuid solution, if you have wss:// (secured) chances of spoofing and MITM is very less

Comment: @MukeshVerma wss wouldn't help because someone can still open the client code in their browser and alter the ID per websocket (I have no idea why anyone would do this, but it's definitely a possibility).